# This page isn’t working HTTP ERROR 405 in asp.net core when click the link in email

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When I send an email with link for user to reset their password and user click the link, the error:

> This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site owner.

HTTP error 405 appeared.

Here is my controller:

```
[Route("ResetPassword")]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string id)
{
    return View(new ResetPasswordViewModel()
            {
                ActiveCode = id
            });
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("ResetPassword")]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel reset)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(reset);

    DataLayer.Entities.User.User user = _userService.GetUserByActiveCode(reset.ActiveCode);

    if (user == null)
        return NotFound();

    string HashNewPassword = PasswordHelper.EncodePasswordMD5(reset.Password);
    user.Password = HashNewPassword;

    _userService.UpdateUser(user);

    return Redirect("/Login");
}
```

And this is my view:

```
<div class="register-area ptb-100">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="register">
            <h3>بازیابی رمز عبور</h3>
            <form asp-action="ResetPassword" method="post">        
                
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="ActiveCode" />

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input asp-for="Password" type="password" id="password2" class="form-control" placeholder="رمز عبور*">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input asp-for="RePassword" type="password" id="password3" class="form-control" placeholder="تکرار رمز عبور*">
                    <span asp-validation-for="RePassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="default-btn btn">اعمال تغییرات</button>
                <div>
                    <a href="/Login">ورود </a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the email:

```
<div style="direction:rtl; padding:20px;">
    <h2>@Model.UserName عزیز!</h2>
    <p>جهت بازیابی رمز عبور روی لینک زیر کلیک کنید</p>
    <p>
        <a href="https://localhost:44359/Account/ResetPassword/@Model.ActivCode">بازیابی رمز عبور</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

and these are the endpoints:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");            
            });
```

so.. where's the problem?

Comment: You are using localhost href in the email template?

Comment: Is route Account/ResetPassword or just ResetPasswrod

Comment: Have you used postman to test this is the correct route to `ResetPassword` get endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

405 errors indicate that the method you are trying to use (GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE) is not allowed. Either it does not exist on that endpoint, you do not have the necessary permissions, or it is blocked by CORS.

It could be that you are simply not calling your endpoint correctly, maybe you have not gotten the address right, either way, this error is primarily due to an improperly configured API route.

Comment: here are the endpoints:

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");            
            });

Comment: Do you have a swagger page to view and test your endpoints? Or have you tried calling this endpoint in Postman/Insomnia?